# Having an issue getting user id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

So I am working on building a web app and I have a lot of it working.  However I am trying to link my user._id to my items database.  But when I try to post an item using postman the app crashes saying it cant read property '_id' of null.  I know I am missing something but I honestly can't figure out what other code I need to implement.  Any help would be great. Thanks

Here is the code for the UserSchema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 15
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 15
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 15
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpires: Date,
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

Here is the code for the ItemSchema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./user');

const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 20
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  createdBy: {
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User"
    },
    username: String
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("items", ItemSchema);
```

And here is the code for the route thats throwing the error:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/user");

router.route("/item/add")
.post(function(req, res) {
  User.findById(req.user._id, function(user, err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    var item = new Item();
    item.name = req.body.name;
    item.description = req.body.description;
    item.price = req.body.price;
    item.createdBy = { id: req.user._id, username: req.user.username };

    item.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
      res.json({ message: "Item was successfully saved" });
      console.log(item);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I see that you are using `passport-local-mongoose`. You will need to log in the user for the user to be available in `req.user`. Read more here: [Configure Passport/Passport-Local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local-mongoose#configure-passportpassport-local) and [passport-local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#authenticate-requests)

Comment: Point being that `req.user` is `null` ( or simply non-existent ) until you actually have something authenticated  and there is actually something in the property. If you still don't understand, then you should show how you have the passport authentication set up and where you expect that the current user is being authenticated and retrieved from session, as the problem will most certainly be there.

Comment: I am logged in while trying to use this.  And logging in and logging out works because of middleware that checks to see if a user is logged in before allowing specific actions.  What code would you need to see.  It's on github if you want to check it out there ... https://github.com/dpawson905/inventoryApp

Comment: Ok, so if I am not logged in, the app crashes saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.  However, If I am logged in console.log just says null.  So I know it's partially working.  But I just don't understand why it's saying null

Comment: Ok, I got it to work ... So for some reason using router.get and router.post work fine and pull the user info from the database.  However if I use router.route and then group my .get and .post and other crud operations together ... It doesnt work.  So, it's working

Answer (score -1):

You need to send your data in json format in postman for example:
`{'id':1, 'name':'jhon doe', 'email':'jhondoe@example.com'}`

in your backend file you need to call 
`req.body.id` not `req.user._id`

Comment: This is good for testing probably. But the OP here is using `passport-local-mongoose` which, given that the user is logged in, the user object is made available in the `req.user` object.